# Using Return values in Railway Programming in C#

Tags: c#

I have just started using Railway Orientated Programming and it seems to reduce the code when you have a lot of functions to call, based on the previous call failing.

However, I don't know what to do if I need to use a return value from one of the items in an OnSuccess call and used it in the next call?

**Example:**

Function 2 returns a value ('param1') that I want to include in the call to Function 3:

```
Function1()
    .OnSuccess(() => Function2())
    .OnSuccess(() => Function3(param1))
    .OnBoth(result => AddtoLog(result));
```

Is there a way to do this in Railway-Orientated Programming?

Comment: What's the type of `OnSuccess`? I would expect it to be `TSuccess -> Result<TSuccess, TFailure>` in which case the lambda you pass to it should take the result of the previous operation. Then you would do `OnSuccess(result => Function3(param1, result))`.

Comment: Railway programming isn't about Success/Failure methods. The success type should contain the result. It is the *wagon* that rans on the rails and the result is the cargo. Where is the success type? Ideally It should be something like `Success<TResult>`

Comment: Also, the second line doesn't do anything with the cargo, it simply ignores it. It should be `OnSuccess(msg=>Function3(msg))` and return another wagon. I suspect you implemented something other than Railway oriented programming

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I guess I am missing something and will go and do some more research.